# I have a wallet setup and bought Bitcoin from 2010, I remember the password.... What would I need to recover the wallet today?

Tags: wallet

What info do I need to recover my Bitcoin wallet from 2010?

Answer (score -1):

sorry to say but if you only have a password its not possible to recover it
only possible options from where you can recover it is by:
1-seed phrase
2-private keys
3-a wallet backup
,The process of recovering might differ a little bit depending on the wallet application you used